# Outlook reply emails lose structure after moving to a folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have been organizing emails by moving them to different folders.
However, I realized that although emails can be organized in a tree structure for forwarded and replied emails, after being moved to my custom-defined folders they fell apart into individual single emails. How should I move those emails to folders while still maintaining the reply messages' relationships/structures?
I've been using Microsoft 2018 Version 16.16.13.

Comment: It sounds like you have the conversation view enabled in the original folder. It must also be enabled in the destination folder to continue seeing messages in the threaded view. Do you have this enabled in the destination folder?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator OK Indeed!!! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Twisty Impersonator, enabling conversation view helped. Here's what I did on Mac:

1. Click on the folder
2. From the top menu bar click View
3. Check "Show as conversations"